# How do I make an HTTP request using cookies on UWP?

Tags: http, cookies, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'd like to make an http request to a remote server while properly handling cookies (eg. storing cookies sent by the server, and sending those cookies when I make subsequent requests). It'd be nice to preserve any and all cookies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built in `Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient` can manage cookies if you pass in an instance of `HttpBaseProtocolFilter` to its constructor. This class then has a `CookieManager` property which contains the cookies and you can even modify it and add your custom cookies for next requests.

However, you should instead reference the `System.Net.Http` NuGet package and use its `HttpClient` which always is up-to-date and regularly updated. In this case the `HttpClient` class accepts a `HttpClientHandler` instance in its constructor and this class in turn has the `CookieContainer` property which works in a similar manner as `CookieManager` in `Windows.Web.Http`.

### `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`

**Send custom cookie**

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer(),
    UseCookies = true
};
var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(handler);
handler.CookieContainer.Add(targetUri, new System.Net.Cookie("name", "value"));
var response = await client.GetAsync(targetUri);
```

**Retrieve cookie**

```
var cookie = handler.CookieContainer["name"];
```

### `Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient`

**Send custom cookie**

```
var filter = new Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter()
{
    CookieUsageBehavior = Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpCookieUsageBehavior.Default
};
filter.CookieManager.SetCookie(new Windows.Web.Http.HttpCookie("name", "domain", "path")
{
    Value = "value"
});
var client =  new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient(filter);
var response = await client.GetAsync(targetUri);
```

**Retrieve a cookie**

```
var cookie = filter.CookieManager.GetCookies(targetUri).
              FirstOrDefault(cookie => cookie.Name == "name");
```

Comment: if you can add code block with post request it will be very helpful. Thank you

Comment: Oh, sure I will, once I get home

Comment: Oh sorry, completely forgot . I will update the post shortly

Comment: Okay, I have added samples for both cases